# What's the advantage of using epoll_create1() instead of epoll_create()

Tags: c, asynchronous, network-programming, epoll

I'm rewriting a multithread Linux-2.6.32+ application to replace [`select`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) with [`epoll`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html).

The man pages for [epoll_create1(2)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_create1.2.html) declare that:

> If flags is 0, then, other than the fact that **the obsolete size argument** is dropped, epoll_create1() is the same as epoll_create().

Yet, isn't this *obsolete size argument* used in [`epoll_wait(2)`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) as `maxevents`?

```
epoll_wait(int epfd, struct epoll_event *events,
                  int maxevents, int timeout);
```

This means when using epoll we can avoid declaring the maximum number of events in `epoll_create1` but sooner or later we have to reference it when calling `epoll_wait`? If so, what's the point of bringing `epoll_create1` into the game?

Thanks for enlighten me on this subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `epoll_wait()`, `maxevents` tells you you maximum number of events that will be *returned* to you. It has nothing to do with how many are maintained within the kernel.

Older versions of `epoll_create()` used the size to set certain limits but that's no longer done, hence the comment that the `size` argument is obsolete. This is made evident by the source code (in [`fs/eventpoll.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/eventpoll.c#L2093) as at the time of this answer):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(epoll_create1, int, flags) {
    return do_epoll_create(flags);
}
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(epoll_create, int, size) {
    if (size <= 0) return -EINVAL;
    return do_epoll_create(0);
}
```

You can see that they're almost identical except that:

- `epoll_create1()` accepts flags, passing them on to `do_epoll_create()`;
- `epoll_create()` accepts size, checking it, but otherwise ignoring it;
- `epoll_create()` passes default flags (none) to `do_epoll_create()`.

Hence the advantage of using `epoll_create1()` is that it allows you to specify the flags, which I think are currently limited to close-on-exec (so that the file descriptor is automatically closed when `exec`-ing another program).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. In `epoll_create1` I just let the kernel itself to dimension it's internal structures, alright. I was thinking the `maxevents` parameter was going to be dropped as well but that's not the case.

Answer (score 3):

the `epoll_create1()` supply a way to set a flag. Needless to set the size now.

actually in the kernel source code: /fs/eventpoll.c

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(epoll_create, int, size)
{
    if (size <= 0)
        return -EINVAL;

    return sys_epoll_create1(0);
}
```

the `epoll_wait()` paramete `max_events` is for controlling return fd count not the total fd count in the whole `eventpoll` struct

Comment: OK, I see now that the `size` argument of `epoll_create` and  `maxevents` of `epoll_wait` are not the same thing. Thanks.